# App profile page versus m.facebook.com

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-ios-sdk

Can this be true, or am I missing something, big time? It seems there's no way to access a Facebook app's profile page on the Facebook mobile site (m.facebook.com)?

I thought I wouldn't need to create a separate fan page for my app now that the app's profile page kind of looks and feels like a regular fan page. But if it's not accessible in Facebook mobile, then it's no use to me whatsoever - the thing is, I'm developing a native iPhone app, and the Facebook app is just for sharing the results, promoting and building fanbase - in other words I need a "Visit app's Facebook page" button in my iPhone app, and obviously the link should open in m.facebook.com, not the full www.facebook.com site.

I have no problem opening regular fan pages in Facebook mobile on my iPhone, or opening app's profile pages in the regular Facebook site. But I can't seem to be able to access any app's profile page in Facebook mobile. Please tell me I'm just dumb and there's of course a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few ways that I was able to make it work.

Named pages

- m.facebook.com/coke
- m.facebook.com/facebook
- m.facebook.com/yupiq

Applications

- m.facebook.com/profile.php?id=150980384961454

Does that solve it for you?

EDIT:

I was unable to get the `m.facebook.com/{id}` to work for anything.

Comment: Thank you! The "profile.php?id=" format works! You saved my day! Funny that I wasn't able to find such a basic info in the official FB dev docs anywhere. I tried the same url formats that open the page in the full site, but none of them worked.

Comment: – I made the logical, but seemingly false assumption that the mobile site url format would be something along the lines of the full site url: https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=myappid&sk=wall

BTW, I had made yet another false assumption – that m.facebook.com and touch.facebook.com were identical. They're not – the latter seems touch screen optimised, logically enough. So I'll be using touch.facebook.com/profile?id=myappid from now on. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I must warn you though, I used to use `www.facebook.com/profile.php?id={id}` on the full site, but recently that stopped working for some pages and applications (but, lukily, it seems that facebook.com/{id} started working for everything). I don't know if this also affects what you are working on, but it might be a problem if you are dynamically generating a lot of links to new sets of applications and pages. In other words, be wary of the undocumented facebook changes to urls.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Luckily, for now I only have a single button with one hard-coded url link in my app.

Comment: Ironically enough, I ran to yet another FB problem right away... the story continues [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7960373/touch-facebook-com-on-iphone-giving-me-entity-nbsp-not-defined)